# How to parse json array without json object title in android ? Help me

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
[
   {
      "configurationId":1,
      "configurationName":"CGST",
      "configurationVal":"2.5"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":2,
      "configurationName":"SGST",
      "configurationVal":"2.5"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":3,
      "configurationName":"DELIVERY_CHARGE",
      "configurationVal":"0"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":4,
      "configurationName":"Admin_Mobile",
      "configurationVal":"9500100042,8939404592"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":5,
      "configurationName":"MIN_ORDER_AMOUNT",
      "configurationVal":"98"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":6,
      "configurationName":"Packing_charge",
      "configurationVal":"3"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":7,
      "configurationName":"available_areas",
      "configurationVal":"{\"availableAreas\":[{\"area_id\": \"1\",\"area_name\": \"Velachery\",\"pincode\": \"600042\"},{\"area_id\": \"2\",\"area_name\": \"Nanganallur\",\"pincode\": \"600061\"},{\"area_id\": \"3\",\"area_name\": \"Adambakkam\",\"pincode\": \"323546\"},{\"area_id\": \"4\",\"area_name\": \"Madipakkam\",\"pincode\": \"600091\"},{\"area_id\": \"5\",\"area_name\": \"Perungudi\",\"pincode\": \"600096\"},{\"area_id\": \"6\",\"area_name\": \"Pallikarani\",\"pincode\": \"600100\"}]}"
   },
   {
      "configurationId":8,
      "configurationName":"order_timing",
      "configurationVal":"[{\n\t\"start_time\": \"17:00:00\",\n\t\"end_time\": \"03:00:00\"\n}]"
   }
]
```

Comment: what if we convert it in Model Class. and then  convert ConfigurationVal  according to required class.?

Comment: Is it still a valid json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal whenever I do a lot of coding for answers if to make sure you actually understand what you are doing and not just copy and paste my code into your project. If you never worked with `instanceof`, I advise you to read up on it. If you have **ANY** questions, please ask me.

I will get you started. Why? You showing no code in your post, so I will explain what to do with this.

```
    JSONArray object = new JSONArray(jsonData);
    //jsonData if the JSON String.
    String configVal = null;

    JSONArray configArray = null;
    JSONArray timingArray = null;

    boolean hasAreas = false;
    boolean hasTiming = false;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject getJSONObject = object.optJSONObject(i);

            if (getJSONObject.get("configurationVal") instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject configValObject = getJSONObject.getJSONObject("configurationVal");
                configArray = configValObject.getJSONArray("availableAreas");
                hasAreas = true;
            } else if (getJSONObject.get("configurationVal") instanceof JSONArray) {
                timingArray = getJSONObject.getJSONArray("configurationVal");
                hasTiming = true;
            }  else {
                configVal = getJSONObject.getString("configurationVal");
            }


            String configName = getJSONObject.getString("configurationName");
            int configId = getJSONObject.getInt("configurationId");

            if (hasAreas) {
                System.out.println("ConfigVal: " + configVal + ", ConfigName: " + configName + ", ConfigId: " + configId + ", AreaInformation: " + configArray);
            }
            if (hasTiming) {
                System.out.println("ConfigVal: " + configVal + ", ConfigName: " + configName + ", ConfigId: " + configId + ", TimingInfo: " + timingArray);
            } 
            if (!hasAreas && !hasTiming) {
                System.out.println("ConfigVal: " + configVal + ", ConfigName: " + configName + ", ConfigId: " + configId);
            }   
            //Reset these...
            hasAreas = false;
            hasTiming = false;
            configVal = null;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will print out the following.

```
ConfigVal: 2.5, ConfigName: CGST, ConfigId: 1
ConfigVal: 2.5, ConfigName: SGST, ConfigId: 2
ConfigVal: 0, ConfigName: DELIVERY_CHARGE, ConfigId: 3
ConfigVal: 9500100042,8939404592, ConfigName: Admin_Mobile, ConfigId: 4
ConfigVal: 98, ConfigName: MIN_ORDER_AMOUNT, ConfigId: 5
ConfigVal: 3, ConfigName: Packing_charge, ConfigId: 6
ConfigVal: , ConfigName: available_areas, ConfigId: 7, AreaInformation: [{"area_name":"Velachery","pincode":"600042","area_id":"1"},{"area_name":"Nanganallur","pincode":"600061","area_id":"2"},{"area_name":"Adambakkam","pincode":"323546","area_id":"3"},{"area_name":"Madipakkam","pincode":"600091","area_id":"4"},{"area_name":"Perungudi","pincode":"600096","area_id":"5"},{"area_name":"Pallikarani","pincode":"600100","area_id":"6"}]
ConfigVal: , ConfigName: order_timing, ConfigId: 8, TimingInfo: [{"start_time":"17: 00: 00","end_time ":"03: 00: 00"}]
```

Now, has you can see, the available_areas and order_timing is not parsed. I did, however, give you the information in a JSONArray. So you can follow what I did and parse it out. However, I would use a model for this with a List<>. It would be easier to work with.

Comment: protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            JSONArray object = new JSONArray(jsonData);
            //jsonData if the JSON String.
            String configVal = null;
            JSONArray configArray = null;
            JSONArray timingArray = null;
            boolean hasAreas = false;
            boolean hasTiming = false;

Comment: change jsonData to jsonStr.... thats what it looks like your getting at the response.

Comment: ya sir changed but when I run in the ph the "please wait" dialogue appears

Comment: well, i got it printed on my end... so perhaps its catching an exception. check logs.

Comment: Sir thanks  its printing for me but I can't separate the pincode and area names in configuration 7

Comment: @rahulSarath its a JSONArray... how do you parse JSONArray? The answer is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to parse the JsonArray.

```
String jsonStr = "[{ "configurationId": 1, "configurationName": "CGST",........]";
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    int configurationId = jsonobject.getInt("configurationId");
    String configurationName = jsonobject.getString("configurationName");
    String configurationVal = jsonobject.getString("configurationVal");
}
```

For the last 2 "configurationVal" are JsonObject itself. So you've to parse again.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: the very last ConfigurationValue is a json object, not a string

Comment: I can see the last ConfigurationValue is ---> "configurationVal": "[{\n\t\"start_time\": \"17:00:00\",\n\t\"end_time\": \"03:00:00\"\n}]". So its a String until you parse again. And check other "ConfigurationValue" are also String.

Comment: Hello, @rahul please try once my solution. I think it'll work. And see in your jsonArray there is some String value which is like jsonObject. So you've to parse again with JsonObject.

Comment: And  I'm in need of "configuration ID"=7 to display the list of pincode

Comment: String configurationVal =jsonobject.getString("configurationVal");
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(configurationVal);
Stringarea=jsonobj.getJSONArray("availableAreas");
Then follow get the pincode from that jsonArray.